# delete mother object if exception thrown in member

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

I have the following issue:

I want to delete a mother object if an exception is thrown inside the constructor of one of its members.
How do I do that?

The following does NOT what I want. Just you have something to refer to...

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{

    A(int i)
    :mem(0)
    {
        try{
            if(i > 9) throw 0;
        }catch(int x) { std::cout << "mem max size 9\n"; return;}
        mem = i;
    }

    int mem;
};

struct B
{
    B(int i)
    :mem(i)
    {
    }

    const A mem;

};

int main()
{

    B b1(2);
    B b2(10);

    std::cout << "b1: " << b1.mem.mem << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b2: " << b2.mem.mem << std::endl;

}

//~ output:
//~ mem max size 9
//~ b1: 2
//~ b2: 0
```

## Edit

Following [this link](http://gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm) I changed my code as follows

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{

    A(int i)
    :mem(0)
    {
        if(i > 9) throw 0;
        else mem = i;
    }

    int mem;
};

struct B
{
    B(int i)
    try
    :mem(i)
    {
    }
    catch(int e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error #" << e << std::endl;
    }

    const A mem;
};

int main()
{
    B b1(2);
    B b2(10);
}

//~ output:
//~ Error #0
//~ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
//~ Aborted
```

But, I don't want the program to abort... how can I prevent that?

If I do it like this, the program does not get aborted but the B object is being constructed despite the exception...

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{

    A(int i)
    :mem(0)
    {
        try
        {
            if(i > 9) throw 0;
        }
        catch(int e)
        {
            std::cerr << "A Error #" << e << std::endl; return;
        }
         mem = i;
    }

    int mem;
};

struct B
{
    B(int i)
    try
    :mem(i)
    {
    }
    catch(int e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error #" << e << std::endl;
    }

    const A mem;
};

int main()
{

    B b1(2);
    B b2(10);

    std::cout << "b1: " << b1.mem.mem << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b2: " << b2.mem.mem << std::endl;

}

//~ A Error #0
//~ b1: 2
//~ b2: 0
```

and if I re-throw in the catch in A the program gets aborted again...

Comment: Because you caught the exception in A, the constructor of B does not get the exception.  You could try re-throwing the exception after the message output in A's constructor.

Comment: okay, but how can I catch it from B's initialiser list?

Comment: There is a syntax for it (can't remember it at the moment).  Hopefully someone else can answer that part for you.   try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441009/how-to-catch-the-exception-in-initialization-list

Comment: [How to catch the exception in initialization list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441009/how-to-catch-the-exception-in-initialization-list)

Comment: You shouldn't be catching the exception straight after you throw it. Use a try-block in `main()`.

Comment: If construction of `B::mem` fails, construction of `B` also fails. It doesn't need to (can't, actually) delete itself because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor for `B` isn't getting the exception because the constructor for `A` is catching it.  Get rid of the `try` block there:

```
A(int i)
:mem(0)
{
    if(i > 9) {
        std::cout << "mem max size 9\n";
        throw 0;
    }
    mem = i;
}
```

If you attempt to catch the exception in the initializer list for `B`, it will get re-thrown anyway, so instead of catching the exception there, catch it in `main`:

```
int main()
{
    try {
        B b1(2);
        std::cout << "b1: " << b1.mem.mem << std::endl;
    } catch (int e) {
        std::cout << "failed to create b1" << std::endl;
    }
    try {
        B b2(10);
    } catch (int e) {
        std::cout << "failed to create b2" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see... hm But I want this to be a fix property of B. B shall delete itself if A cannot be constructed according to some condition. Is there no way to make this a built in thing of B?

Comment: @lotolmencre Afraid not.  See [this link](http://gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I read the article and actually it does sound like the thing I want... but its not quite working yet. I updated my question post with the new code.

Comment: @lotolmencre It won't do what you want.  Any exception caught from the initializer list automatically gets re-thrown if you don't throw it yourself.  You need to use a `try..catch` block in `main` like my example shows.

Comment: Ok, I reread and figured I had that impression due to wishful reading.Thank you.